# JSON object -> array? how should I convert it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Take two :) I have a jquery's autocomplete texbox and, upon a click of a button, I need to check if the value entered has come from the autocomplete or is it a completely new value.

The problems is that 'cache' is some sort of an array of JSON objects, but to be able to use ***if ( input in cache ) { ... }*** I need to convert it to a simple javascript array. What would be the best way to do that?

P.S. FireBug says 'cache=[object Object]'

```
//////////////////////////////////////////// autocomplete code //////////////////
    var cache = {},
        lastXhr;
    $( "#inputV" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function( request, response ) {
            var term = request.term;
            if ( term in cache ) {
                response( cache[ term ] );
                return;
            }

            lastXhr = $.getJSON( "search.php", request, function( data, status, xhr ) {
                cache[ term ] = data;
                if ( xhr === lastXhr ) {
                    response( data );
                }
            });
        }
    });


////////////////////////// check if input comes from autocomplete  //////////////////
    $('#btn_check').click(function()        {

        var input = $("#inputV").val();
        alert(input);

        console.log('cache='+cache); 
        /// FireBug says 'cache=[object Object]'

        if ( input in cache ) 
            {
                alert("yes");
             }  
            else
            {
                alert("no");
            }   
    });
```

Here's that a response looks like.

```
[
    {
        "id": "Podiceps nigricollis",
        "label": "Black-necked Grebe",
        "value": "Black-necked Grebe"
    },
    {
        "id": "Nycticorax nycticorax",
        "label": "Black-crowned Night Heron",
        "value": "Black-crowned Night Heron"
    },
    {
        "id": "Tetrao tetrix",
        "label": "Black Grouse",
        "value": "Black Grouse"
    },
    {
        "id": "Limosa limosa",
        "label": "Black-tailed Godwit",
        "value": "Black-tailed Godwit"
    },
    {
            "id": "Chlidonias niger",
        "label": "Black Tern",
        "value": "Black Tern"
    },
    {
        "id": "Larus marinus",
        "label": "Great Black-backed Gull",
        "value": "Great Black-backed Gull"
    },
    {
        "id": "Larus fuscus",
        "label": "Lesser Black-backed Gull",
        "value": "Lesser Black-backed Gull"
    },
    {
        "id": "Larus ridibundus",
        "label": "Black-headed Gull",
        "value": "Black-headed Gull"
    },
    {
        "id": "Turdus merula",
        "label": "Common Blackbird",
        "value": "Common Blackbird"
    },
    {
        "id": "Sylvia atricapilla",
        "label": "Blackcap",
        "value": "Blackcap"
    },
    {
        "id": "Rissa tridactyla",
        "label": "Black-legged Kittiwake",
        "value": "Black-legged Kittiwake"
    },
    {
        "id": "Aegypius monachus",
        "label": "Eurasian Black Vulture",
        "value": "Eurasian Black Vulture"
    }
]
```

Comment: *"The problems is that 'cache' is some sort of an array of JSON objects"* **JavaScript** objects. JSON is a notation.

Comment: You defined it as object `var cache = {}`. I don't understand your problem... You should provide an example of `cache` and what you want to transform it into. I think `if ( input in cache )` will work fine.

Comment: if(x in y) would work if x is a string and y is an array of strings. yet in my case x is a string, but y is an array of JavaScript objects. Therefor I first need to convert this object array into a string array.

Comment: You have a misunderstanding of the `in` operator. It does not test whether an element is in an array, it tests whether a property is set on an object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/in . If you use it with an array, you test whether a particular *index* is set.

Comment: Formatting is really important in questions. Posting the JSON as a wall of undifferentiated text isn't ideal. I've taken it, run it through jsonlint.com to format it, and then used the "{}" button in the StackOverflow editor to mark the result as code so it's more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Replacement answer, I hadn't meant the last one to be a CW.)*

> The problems is that 'cache' is some sort of an array of JSON objects

Actually, it's not an array. It's an object. (It's created via `var cache = {};`, which is how we can tell.)

> ...but to be able to use `if ( input in cache ) { ... }` I need to convert it to a simple javascript array.

Actually, no. The `in` operator in this context tests to see if an object contains a property with the name you give it. Example:

```
var obj = {foo: 1};  // An object with a property called "foo"
alert('foo' in obj); // alerts true, `obj` has a "foo" property
alert('bar' in obj); // alerts false, there is no "bar" property in `obj`
```

Note that the left-hand side of the `in` operator must be a string (it can be a literal, as above, or any expression that results in a string, such as a variable reference).

The code in your `click` handler is taking the value of the "inputV" field and seeing if that value is the name of a property in the `cache` object.

You probably want to check if it's the *value* of one of the properties of the `cache` object. If so:

```
$('#btn_check').click(function()        {

    var input = $("#inputV").val();
    var found, propName;

    alert(input);

    console.log('cache='+cache); 
    /// FireBug says 'cache=[object Object]'

    found = false;
    for (propName in cache ) {
        if (cache[propName] == input) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    alert(found);
});
```

Since we know `cache` is a boring old object (from the fact it's created with `var cache = {};`), we can pretty safely use a raw `for..in` loop as above. But if you wanted to be more careful, you would use `hasOwnProperty` to make sure that you only checked propeties that `cache` has its own copy of (as opposed to ones it inherits from its prototype):

```
    for (propName in cache ) {
        if (cache.hasOwnProperty(propName) && cache[propName] == input) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Again, though, it's not really necessary in this case, because we know that `cache` is a plain object, and barring someone doing something really silly like extending `Object.prototype` (which Thou Shalt Not Do), all of its enumerable properties (the things that `for..in` enumerates) are its own properties.

Comment: I would say the OP's code should work as expected. The search term is set as property of the `cache` object, and `if(input in cache)` tests whether the term was searched before...

Comment: @Felix: Could be. :-) I honestly couldn't tell. I started out just addressing the misconception, but then thought perhaps the value-vs-name thing might help.

Comment: Hmm... the concept looks right, but its still not working! :/ For example I start typing "black", it returns me "[ { "id": "Podiceps nigricollis", "label": "Black-necked Grebe", "value": "Black-necked Grebe" }", I click on the "Black-necked Grebe" and when it test it against this cache, I still get a false...

Comment: @Roger: You'll have to walk through the code with a debugger (I think you said you have Firebug, that'd work) and look at the actual value, what's in `cache`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing what the JSON looks like. It's possible that you could substitute `if ( input in cache )` with `if(cache.hasOwnProperty(input))` and not bother converting it to an array, but it depends what the cache object contains.